# How do I get ride of this error, "Unknown column 'history_change_reason'"?

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am running into this error when I try to write to my database. I can't seem to find column `history_change_reason` in my database through mysqlWorkbench. Anyone else dealt with this before?

```
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 861, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 920, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 963, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'history_change_reason' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Did you run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I did yeah @AlexVyushkov

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We just updated our django and are running into this issue. There are no migrations outstanding but migrating didn't seem to do any changes to the historical tables so they don't have the `history_change_reason` column. I'm trying to find a real django solution but fear that I might just need to do a bunch of SQL column additions to add it to each table that uses history (a bunch in my case)